# Reason for $0^-$ bound on unilateral Laplace transform

Tags: laplace-transform

I have the definition of the unilateral $\mathcal{L}$-transform, valid for causal signals, to be:

$$\mathcal{L}\left[f(t)\right](s)=\int_{0^-}^{+\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

My question is regarding the lower integration bound, $t=0^-$. Is this so (as opposed to say, $0^+$, or simply $0$) as to ensure that initial conditions are still considered?

For example, say $f=H$ the Heaviside step function, and there's some non-zero initial condition $f(0)$. From a bound $t=0^+$ we'd surely conclude the value of $f(0)$ played no role; from $t=0$, I suppose it would be more ambiguous, and would - I believe - depend on your definition of $H$: potentially forcing $f(0)=H(0)=0.5$ in the three-valued definition.

Is this correct, or is there some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

$0^- $ means you would include a delta function placed at $t=0$. You still would have to deal with initial conditions whether you had $0^+$ or $0^-$

One of the most common reasons a delta function may appear at $t=0$ is if you differentiate a function multiplied by the step function.

Comment: But what I mean is, if I integrate from $0^+$ a function with support extending just outside that, then I'm going to "see" that value, rather than the "real" initial condition, right?

Comment: Actually this completely depends on your definition of the step function. If you decided that the step function began at $0^+$, this would automatically mean that its derivative (delta function) also began at $0^+$ and you could pick the lower bound to be $0^+$ and nothing would change. A more robust definition would be: $$\int _{-\infty}^\infty f(t)u(t)e^{-st}dt$$ where $u(t)$ is the step function. If you define it this way, you automatically tell that the bounds should be chosen according to your preferred definition of the step function.

Comment: Ah, thank you, that was probably the root of the derivation and I just pulled the step out into the bounds in my notes. I'm still not totally clear on the implications (e.g. the mid-point $H(0)=0.5$?) but it's certainly clearer in that form, so I think I'll stick with it.